# Can't sync iCloud mail

Tags: windows-10, apple-mail, icloud

I'm trying to set the Mail app to sync my iCloud email but it won't. I am using an app-specific password. My iCloud account's calendar and contacts have been successfully connected and synced but only the mail part won't. Whenever I turn on the switch and click save and open back the settings, I find that it's turned off.

What gives?

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: Have you worked through https://support.apple.com/HT202304 ? Set up 2FA?

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned that. I am using the app-specific password. EVERYTHING syncs except for mail. Calendar and contacts sync fine. It's only mail that switches itself off as I showed in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this was a while ago, but I had the same problem and just figured it out. I was using a gmail account as my appleid and also using that same gmail account as my primary email. Once I changed my appleid back to the ""@icloud.com I was able to sync my mail. Hopefully this helps